# Connecting my tab buttons to pages

Tags: lua, coronasdk, tabbar

I'm creating a basic quiz game in corona for a class and am having troubles getting my tab bar buttons to connect to the other pages that have been created for them.  I was just wondering if anyone out there could help me out.

**main.lua**

```
local background = display.newImage ("basketball_court.jpg")
print("PE Sports Quiz")

display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar )

local textObj = display.newText("PE Sports Quiz",
100, 50, m11, 24)
textObj:setTextColor(250,250,250)

local widget = require ( "widget" )
local storyboard = require("storyboard")
local scene = storyboard.newScene()
local localGroup = display.newGroup()

local tabButtons =
{
    {
    width = 32, height = 32,
    defaultFile = "tab.png",
    overFile = "tab2.png",
    label = "Play",
    onPress = function() storyboard.gotoScene( "basketball1" ); end, 
    selected = true
},
{
    width = 32, height = 32,
    defaultFile = "tab.png",
    overFile = "tab2.png",
    label = "Credits",
    onPress = function() storyboard.gotoScene( "credits" ); end,
}
}

local demoTabs = widget.newTabBar
{
  top = display.contentHeight - 50,
  width = display.contentWidth,
  backgroundFile = "back.png",
  tabSelectedLeftFile = "tab.png",
  tabSelectedMiddleFile = "tab.png",
  tabSelectedRightFile = "tab.png",
  tabSelectedFrameWidth = 20,
  tabSelectedFrameHeight = 52,
  buttons = tabButtons
}

local tabBar = widget.newTabBar
{
  top = display.contentHeight - 50,
  width = display.contentWidth,
  buttons = tabButtons
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I see is that you should rename your credits.lua to gamecredits.lua and change the gotoScene() call for it.  There is an internal module called "credits" that can cause issues.